# What value will android:minSdkVersion be greater than if I don't hope to import v4 and v7 compatible package?

Tags: android

I know that I need to import android.support.v4.app or import android.support.v7.app in order to make my app can run under low android SDK.

But sometimes android.support.v4.app and android.support.v7.app will cause some problems.

I will give up low android SDK in my new app.

1:  In order not to import android.support.v4.app or import android.support.v7.app, what value will android:minSdkVersion be set?

2: What else things should I do in order not to import android.support.v4.app or import android.support .v7.app?

Comment: It depends on the functionality you want to support. For example, permissions are from 21, multi screen is from 26, foreground service is from 28 and so on. So there is no hard and fast rule of what must be minimum. Depends on your requirements. And specifically talking about supprt libraries, most of them can be ignored after 21 but make sure your app doesnt use AppCompat or support library objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do, the support libraries have a few usage:

> **Backward Compatibility for newer APIs** - A large amount of the support libraries provide backward compatibility for newer framework
> classes and methods. For example, the Fragment support class provides
> support for fragments on devices running versions earlier than Android
> 3.0 (API level 11).
>
> **Convenience and Helper Classes** - The support libraries provides a number of helper classes, particularly for user interface development.
> For example the RecyclerView class provides an user interface widget
> for displaying and managing very long lists, useable on versions of
> Android from API level 7 and up.
>
> **Debugging and Utilities** - There are a number of features that provide utility beyond code you incorporate into your app, including
> the support-annotations library for improved code lint checks on
> method inputs and Multidex support for configuring and distributing
> apps with over 65,536 methods.

So, for example if you want to use a feature introduced in **recent** platform on devices that running **earlier** versions of the platform, use the equivalent classes and methods from the support library.

If you use a library like `Design`, `RecyclerView`, `FCM` that depends on support library to provide **Compatibility** for those library it's better to use support library (usually other com.android.support.* and com.goole.* libraries).

In other cases feel free to not import the support libraries!

P.S: Still I think the problem with support libs are easier to solve rather the ones you get when not using them.

Comment: Thanks! If I only require the app run under SDK 26 or high, minSdkVersion  is 26,
 targetSdkVersion is 26 or higher, does it mean that I don't need to import android.support.v4.app and android.support.v7.app ?

Comment: Yes, the support library main aim is to bring compatibility to all platform versions, since you target only the latest versions you won't have to use them unless you want to use a feature in newer versions e.g. 27 and still supporting your current version (e.g. 26)